# How can we distinguish between stative passive and passive sentence structures?

Tags: grammar

I want clarification on whether the sentence
"Medusa, a dreaded monster whose hair was made of hissing serpents"
is constructed in a stative passive form or a passive sentence form.

I mean could "made" be considered as a stative passive adjective?

Comment: That's not a sentence. It's just two consecutive noun phrases in apposition. I don't see any "passive" constructions, either.

Comment: Yes, the full sentence is this; "Do you think it is possible to defeat an opponent so fierce that a glance at her turns one to stone?
This was the fate of anyone who looked upon Medusa, a dreaded monster
whose hair was made of hissing serpents."

Comment: Now I want to know if "her hair was made of hissing serpents" is a passive voice structure or not.

Comment: I suppose it is ("made of hissing serpents" looks syntactically the same as, say, *Her hair was **dyed***), but I can't see what use the label "stative passive" is in this context.

Comment: In your opinion, would there be any difference in meaning between the clause parsed as a "stative passive" and the one parsed as "passive voice"?

Comment: Yes. 1. We were tired of Bob. 2. We were tired by Bob. The first sentence uses the "stative passive" construction, while the second sentence employs the passive voice structure.

Comment: So 1 *whose hair was made **of** hissing serpents* = "stative passive", 2 *whose hair was made **by** hissing serpents* = "passive voice". But what *use* is the category?

Answer (score 2):

#### Some clarification first:

According to [grammarbank](https://www.grammarbank.com/stative-verbs.html):

> When a verb **describes a state rather than an action**, it’s called stative(state) verb, and it can only be used in simple tenses.

[Passive voice](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/academic_writing/active_and_passive_voice/verbs_voice_and_mood.html) refers to when the subject of a verb is the object of that verb's action (rather than active voice, when the subject performs the action of the verb). Whether a verb is stative or not has nothing to do with the voice of the verb in question -- it only depends on whether the verb describes a state of being. Both active and passive voice can be used with stative verbs.

**All passive stative verb constructions *are* passive verb constructions**. A more meaningful disctinction might be whether the verb construction is stative or not, or whether a verb is in active or passive voice.

#### Your specific question:

As @FumbleFingers pointed out, your original question is not a sentence, but a sentence fragment.

> Medusa, a dreaded monster whose hair was made of hissing serpents

This construction is an [appositive](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/grammar/appositives.html) of the proper noun "Medusa" and the [noun phrase](https://www.grammarbook.com/blog/nouns/noun-phrase/), "a dreaded monster whose hair was made of hissing serpents", which describes Medusa. Inside of this noun phrase, "a dreaded monster" is the referent of the [defining relative clause](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/relative-clauses-defining-and-non-defining) "whose hair was made of hissing serpents." Because the hair's composition is being described here, this verb is indicating a state of being (not the act of making something), so **yes, "was made" is a stative passive verb in this example.**

**Note:** This is not an adjective (verbs are not adjectives), but it is part of the [adjectival phrase](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/adjectival_phrase.htm) "was made of hissing serpents".